# How the errors of each epoch must look like in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

This is the first model I created in PyTorch and I'm new to this field. I ran the model for a few epochs and this is the output of errors for each epoch for two runs of the algorithm.

[image]
[image]

I also tried 100 epochs, and this is the result

[image]

The iterations denote the epochs and error is the error rate of the last input training sample for each epoch. I would like to know if the output is OK, or it must be descending? Here is the code with dataset [pima-indians-diabetes.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kumargh/pimaindiansdiabetescsv). **If there is anything wrong with my code, I would be appreciated if you let me on it.**

> I also modified learning rate for smaller values, but nothing happend.

This is file `dataset.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


class DataSet:
    divide_rate = 0.8
    file = './pima-indians-diabetes.csv'

    def __init__(self):
        dataframe = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        train_size = int(self.divide_rate * len(dataframe))

        train_set = dataframe.iloc[:train_size, :]
        train_label = train_set['label']
        train_feature = train_set.loc[:, train_set.columns != 'label']
        sc = StandardScaler()
        train_feature = sc.fit_transform(train_feature)
        self.train_labels = torch.tensor(train_label.values, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.train_features = torch.tensor(train_feature, dtype=torch.float32)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.train_features[index], self.train_labels[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.train_features)
```

and this is the main file

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.optim import SGD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from dataset import DataSet
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    input_dim = 8
    hidden_dim = 4
    output_dim = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = [
            nn.Linear(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)
        ]

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(self.layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = torch.sigmoid(layer(x))
        return x


dataset = DataSet()
model = NeuralNetwork()
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=True)

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
Epochs = 10
loss_per_epoch = []
x = []
for i in range(Epochs):
    x.append(i)
    ll = 0
    for feature, label in train_loader:
        pred = model(feature)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, label.unsqueeze(1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        ll = loss.item()
    loss_per_epoch.append(ll)
sns.lineplot(x=x,
                 y=loss_per_epoch,
                 color='green',
                 linewidth=1.5)
plt.ylabel('Error')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
```

As [@M H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21281213/m-h) mentioned, I added the average error of each epoch and this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes in the initial epochs the loss does look like that, three points to note here:

1. I would either take the average training error for all samples in each epoch or even better to avoid noticing at overfitting, I'd take the average validation set error and then plot things.
2. I would want to try this out with more epochs, 10 seems like a very small number.
3. If I'm doing this seriously, I would also try more combinations of number of hidden units and especially learning rate i.e.(maybe learning rate in [1e-4, 3e-2, 0.1]) and do a couple more epochs for each to see the best parameters for the model.

Comment: I tried 100 epochs and added the result, I also added the average error of each error for 200 epochs. You are right. The average of error is OK